# 1 NIC and 2 different IP on 2 VM on VMWARE

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere

I have a test server which has single NIC and I have 2 VM on that server. What i need to do is assigning different IP address to those VM. So the host is located at 192.168.100.67.

would that be possible to assign 2 different ip address from a single NIC on the host ? and how to configure that ?

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: The ip address assigned to the host NIC is unrelated to the ip addresses assigned to your virtual machines.

Comment: @EEAA I manage the host with VMWare client and i cant add virtual switches to route the VM

Answer (score 1):

Possible, several way to do this.

Look onto your virtualization host as to the virtual intelligent L2 switch to which your virtual machines are patched.

First, no one said you should have all addresses on same ethernet segment in same network. It is pretty possible to have several different networks in the same segment and have a router to make it possible to communicate. For example, consider this setup:

```
Router(192.168.1.1/24, 192.168.2.1/24) ===SW---VM1(192.168.1.2/24)
                                           |
                                          VM2(192.168.2.2/24)
```

VM1 and VM2 will communicate with each other through router, unless you set up direct "interface" routes on the.

So you could simply set up desired addresses in VMs, all complication (if this is really complication, there is nothing hard in this) will be on your router which will have addresses from different networks on a single interface.

The second idea is to have smart switch or router and to really split segments using VLANs. VMWare could put different VMs into different VLANs http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004074 and your L3 switch or router next to virtualization host will do inter-vlan routing. The picture basically looks like above, but now router has these IPs on different subinterfaces, VMs are really in different network segments and only could communicate via router. And be careful to leave administrative vlan to access your host itself.

Comment: how do i approach this ? I am using VMware client now and managing everything with that ... but i dont know how to create a switch

Comment: @KonzMama You'll need to read VMware's documentation. We cannot guide you step-by-step through the whole process. So, buckle down for a few days and learn it on your own, or hire someone to help you out.